Using AWS, how do we write from Managed Flink SQL to Firehose?
New to Flink - trying to learn the ropes!  I'm currently writing events to AWS Kinesis Data Streams, which is being ingested by Apache Flink (Zeppelin) under the guise of an AWS Kinesis Studio Notebook.  The data is making its way into the right AWS Glue table without trouble, and I can see it in realtime in my Zeppelin note.
The first paragraph looks like so:
CREATE TABLE analytics_table (
    instance_id INT,
    internal BOOLEAN,
    locale VARCHAR(5),
    content VARCHAR(6),
    content_id INT,
    event_time TIMESTAMP(3),
    WATERMARK FOR event_time AS event_time - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
)
PARTITIONED BY (instance_id)
WITH (
    'connector' = 'kinesis',
    'stream' = 'source-kinesis-stream',
    'aws.region' = 'us-east-1',
    'scan.stream.initpos' = 'LATEST',
    'format' = 'json',
    'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601'
)

The second paragraph tumbles the table to give me the data I want:
%flink.ssql(type=update)

SELECT 
  window_start, 
  window_end, 
  instance_id, 
  content_id, 
  internal, 
  COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM 
  TABLE(
    TUMBLE(
      TABLE analytics_table, 
      DESCRIPTOR(event_time), 
      INTERVAL '1' MINUTES
    )
  )
GROUP BY 
  (
    window_start, window_end, instance_id, 
    content_id, internal
  );

And the right data is appearing on screen when I test the notebook.
The golden question I have, and I can't seem to find the answer whilst searching - is how do I take the data shown in the tumbled table, and write it to Firehose?
I've tried creating a second table using the connector described in the Flink documentation [1] like so:
CREATE TABLE windowed_analytics (
    window_start TIMESTAMP(3),
    window_end TIMESTAMP(3),
    instance_id INT,
    content_id INT,
    internal BOOLEAN,
    locale VARCHAR(5),
    hits INT
)
WITH (
    'connector' = 'firehose',
    'delivery-stream' = 'analytics-sink',
    'aws.region' = 'us-east-1',
    'format' = 'csv',
    'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601'
);


And then modifying the second query to look like so:
%flink.ssql(type=update)

INSERT INTO windowed_analytics
SELECT 
  window_start, 
  window_end, 
  instance_id, 
  content_id, 
  locale,
  internal, 
  COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM 
  TABLE(
    TUMBLE(
      TABLE analytics, 
      DESCRIPTOR(event_time), 
      INTERVAL '1' MINUTES
    )
  )
GROUP BY 
  (
    window_start, window_end, instance_id, 
    content_id, internal, locale
  );

But AWS fails with this error in the stack trace:
Could not find any factory for identifier 'firehose' that implements 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.DynamicTableFactory' in the classpath
[1] https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/firehose/
